# download generated file based on custom serialized data

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm trying to generate a pdf based on checkboxes in a jqgrid.  I post information a MVC controller from the form data and I add some custom serialized data from the checkboxes then the controller returns a file.

```
 data: $("#filter_form").serialize() +"&"+ $.param({"s" : items}),
```

When I use jquery to post the data, but I cant get it on success data back to the browser to save the file.  There is too much data to add it to the url, but when I did that I was successful in downloading the file.  for example  https://www.example.com/controller/action/?data=abc&data=def worked fine, but its not a solution due the amount of data in the url.

I wish I could just use a normal form post, but since I'm serializing some data manually from the checkboxes I was able to figure out how to dynamically add data to a form post.

worst case solution:  I post the data to the controller and then the controller will return a temp URL or key.   Then I could open a up a new window with the temp url or ask the  user to click on it url.  I hope there is a quicker solution.

I'm new to javascript world.  so I hope there is a simple solution that I missed. It must be IE 7 compatible.

Comment: [Your IE7 requirement rules out a **lot** of things you could do](http://caniuse.com/#search=blob%20%7C%20dataURI%20%7C%20download%20). To add data to a form, why not have a hidden `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 0):

this works, but dont know if its the best solution

MVC4 controller actions

```
    //temp store the data because of the custom serialization. Its not possible
    //for ajax post to save file and we cant do it the normal way due to the checkboxes
    [Authorize]
    public void GenerateReport(ContractMaterialFiltersViewModel filters)
    {
        Session["filter"] = filters;
    }

    [Authorize]
    public FileStreamResult Report()
    {
        ContractMaterialFiltersViewModel filters = Session["filter"] as ContractMaterialFiltersViewModel;
        if (filters == null) new Exception("No request data");

   ....
   }
```

now for the Javascript side

```
             //store the filters
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  '<%= Url.Action( "GenerateReport", "GovContractMaterial" ) %>',
            data: $("#filter_form").serialize() +"&"+ $.param({"s" : items}),
            success: function (data) {
                //request file based on stored filters
                ifrm.src = '<%= Url.Action( "Report", "GovContractMaterial" ) %>';
            },
            error: function(request,error) 
            {
                alert ( "Error: " + error );
            }
        });
```